# Why is my Scanner asking for an input twice?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing code for a program I am creating, and all I want this part of my code to do is ask the user to input a number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceRoller {       


    System.out.println("Please input a number of you choice"); 

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    double repeats = x.nextInt(); 

    if(x.hasNextInt()){            
        repeats = (int)Math.round(repeats);


    }          

}
```

So this asks me for a number, but I will have to input twice.

It also only uses the first input as the variable

Comment: Because you told it to ask twice.  Computers (generally) do what you tell them ... not what you meant to tell them :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you got a `nextInt()`, you asked it if it had another input with `hasNextInt()`  it only knows this if you enter something more.

Perhaps you intended to put nextInt() inside the `if` block.  Perhaps you also want to use `int repeats` as its an `int` value.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `x.hasNextInt()` and the Scanner waits for another input to check if it is an int. You are also reading in an int and assigning it to a double (which an int is not). And to further it, you pass your int/double hybrid to Math.round which converts it to a Long and then casts it to an int and tries to assign it to a double.

If you are wanting to check if an a line is an int, you should try something like:

```
System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
String line = x.nextLine();
int res=0;
try{
   res=Integer.parseInt(line);
}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Not a number");
}
```